# Java Nested If/Else Conditionals

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a series of 8 "knockout" if statements that must pass in order to show the appropriate response. If any one of these 8 if statements are failed, the appropriate response is shown. Below is my code...

```
 if (ageCustInt >= ageMinComp1Int && ageCustInt <= ageMaxComp1Int){
            if(adtV1MileageCustInt >= adtVMileageMinComp1Int && adtV2MileageCustInt >= adtVMileageMinComp1Int && adtV3MileageCustInt >= adtVMileageMinComp1Int &&
               adtV1MileageCustInt <= adtVMileageMaxComp1Int && adtV2MileageCustInt <= adtVMileageMaxComp1Int && adtV3MileageCustInt <= adtVMileageMaxComp1Int)
                if(totalViolationsCustInt >= totalViolationsMinComp1Int && totalViolationsCustInt <= totalViolationsMaxComp1Int)
                    if(totalAdtDriversCustInt >= adtDriversMinComp1Int && totalAdtDriversCustInt <= adtDriversMaxComp1Int)
                        if(bodilyInjuryCust.equals(bodilyInjuryComp1))
                            if(propDamageCust.equals(propDamageComp1))
                                if(currentInsur.equals(presInsurKOComp1) || presInsurKOComp1.equals("Both"))
                                    if(unUiBodilyCust.equals(unUiBodilyComp1))
                                    {
                                    btnComp1.setVisible(true);
                                    lblPriceComp1.setText("$ " + price1String);
                                    lblPriceComp1.setVisible(true);
                                    }
        } else
        {
            lblPriceComp1.setText("Not Competitive");
        }
```

I am getting mostly correct results, but every now and then the appropriate "not competitive" result from the else block is not being displayed as it should. My guess here is because the else statement only applies to the very first if statement, and if that is passed than the else block is not executed. I need to structure my if statements so that if ANY of the if statements are failed the else block will execute. I have tried restructuring my blocks with no success. Any ideas?

Comment: The idea is: not to use so many nested IFs...

Comment: Instead of nesting so many ifs, you could chain all of the conditions together with and statements (&&).

Comment: Pull out _all_ those conditions into one function, chained together with `&&`s.  Use one small if.

Answer (score 2):

**As suggested by others, use If chaining concept, using `&&,` merge all conditions into one if block**

Simplest could be below.

```
boolean isValid = false;

     if (ageCustInt >= ageMinComp1Int && ageCustInt <= ageMaxComp1Int){
                if(adtV1MileageCustInt >= adtVMileageMinComp1Int && adtV2MileageCustInt >= adtVMileageMinComp1Int && adtV3MileageCustInt >= adtVMileageMinComp1Int &&
                   adtV1MileageCustInt <= adtVMileageMaxComp1Int && adtV2MileageCustInt <= adtVMileageMaxComp1Int && adtV3MileageCustInt <= adtVMileageMaxComp1Int)
                    if(totalViolationsCustInt >= totalViolationsMinComp1Int && totalViolationsCustInt <= totalViolationsMaxComp1Int)
                        if(totalAdtDriversCustInt >= adtDriversMinComp1Int && totalAdtDriversCustInt <= adtDriversMaxComp1Int)
                            if(bodilyInjuryCust.equals(bodilyInjuryComp1))
                                if(propDamageCust.equals(propDamageComp1))
                                    if(currentInsur.equals(presInsurKOComp1) || presInsurKOComp1.equals("Both"))
                                        if(unUiBodilyCust.equals(unUiBodilyComp1))
                                        {
                                        btnComp1.setVisible(true);
                                        lblPriceComp1.setText("$ " + price1String);
                                        lblPriceComp1.setVisible(true);
                                        }
                                isValid  = true;
            }
```

// later check the variable value if not true, means it has no entered in any if statement.

```
if(!isValid){
     lblPriceComp1.setText("Not Competitive");
}
```

Comment: OP should remember to put code on the next line in appropriate times.

Comment: Yeah, declare a flag to check the condition is right decision. I agree it.

Comment: @Sweeper conditions can be merged, but this just an alternative to OP existing code.

Answer (score 1):

One way to improve readability and solve your quoted problem would be by extracting the individual conditions mentioned by you in methods (thus giving them a name what they are doing)
And calling them using a chain as others have already suggested.

```
private boolean checkAgeLimits(int ageCustInt){
 return (ageCustInt >= ageMinComp1Int) && (ageCustInt <= ageMaxComp1Int);
}
private boolean checkAdtV1MileageCustInt(int adtV1MileageCustInt){
 ...
}
 ...
other validator methods
 ...
if (checkAgeLimits(ageCustInt)
    && checkAdtV1MileageCustInt(adtV1MileageCustInt)
    && .. other validators){
                                        btnComp1.setVisible(true);
                                        lblPriceComp1.setText("$ " + price1String);
                                        lblPriceComp1.setVisible(true);

            } else
            {
                lblPriceComp1.setText("Not Competitive");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

From a complexity level, technically you should never go down more then 3 levels regarding conditional statements or exception handlers. Should you get down to that point, the best advisable route is to split the code out and form its own method. This way you can divide and conquer your logic in a more constructive way, without over complicating your life (or the developer taking over the code).

An example based on your code base can be as follow (I didn't instantiate the objects, as that you'll have to do yourself):

```
/**
 * Add comment on the purpose of this method
 */
public void someMethod() {
    boolean isValid = false;
    if (ageCustInt >= ageMinComp1Int) {
        isValid = checkPointOne();
    }

    if(!isValid){
        lblPriceComp1.setText("Not Competitive");
    }
}

/**
 * Add comment on the purpose of this method
 * @return
 */
public boolean checkPointOne() {
    if (ageCustInt >= ageMinComp1Int && ageCustInt <= ageMaxComp1Int) {

        if (adtV1MileageCustInt >= adtVMileageMinComp1Int
                && adtV2MileageCustInt >= adtVMileageMinComp1Int
                && adtV3MileageCustInt >= adtVMileageMinComp1Int
                && adtV1MileageCustInt <= adtVMileageMaxComp1Int
                && adtV2MileageCustInt <= adtVMileageMaxComp1Int
                && adtV3MileageCustInt <= adtVMileageMaxComp1Int) {
            return checkPointTwo();
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Add comment on the purpose of this method
 * @return
 */
public boolean checkPointTwo() {
    if (totalViolationsCustInt >= totalViolationsMinComp1Int && totalViolationsCustInt <= totalViolationsMaxComp1Int) {

        if (totalAdtDriversCustInt >= adtDriversMinComp1Int && totalAdtDriversCustInt <= adtDriversMaxComp1Int) {
            return checkPointThree();
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Add comment on the purpose of this method
 * @return
 */
public boolean checkPointThree() {
    if (bodilyInjuryCust.equals(bodilyInjuryComp1)) {
        if (propDamageCust.equals(propDamageComp1)) {
            return checkPointFour();
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Add comment on the purpose of this method
 * @return
 */
public boolean checkPointFour() {
    if (currentInsur.equals(presInsurKOComp1) || presInsurKOComp1.equals("Both")) {
        if (unUiBodilyCust.equals(unUiBodilyComp1)) {
            activateForm();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * This method will activate the form
 */
public void activateForm() {
    btnComp1.setVisible(true);
    lblPriceComp1.setText("$ " + price1String);
    lblPriceComp1.setVisible(true);
}
```

Hopefully this can assist you in filtering out the logic you don't require, as this approach will assist you in making better coding choices and not tread down a path to coding hell. Best of luck! :)